# Change software sources from the command line

Tags: command-line, apt, updates, software-sources, mirrors

When I want to change the mirror I am using for updates, I can open the Software Centre, and go to Edit->Software Sources, and from there select another server.

This then goes through my /etc/apt/sources.list file, and replaces all the instances of the old mirror URL, with the new mirror URL.

If, however, I want to do this on the command line (perhaps I'm not running X, or I'm connecting over ssh), I have to go through the /etc/apt/sources.list file myself and change each instance.

This isn't the hardest thing to do, and of course I can do a search and replace, but it is a lot more work than just clicking the name of the server I want, plus it requires me to know a bit about the syntax of the sources.list file, and make sure I don't make an error while editing it.

Is there a command line program which can perform the same task as the Software Centre, and change my update mirror, without me having to edit this file?

Comment: well.. you could use `sed` to replace the server with another with a "s/oldserver/newserver/"

Answer (score 1):

There is no command line GUI program like Software Center that can change in sources.list

You need to look into replacement via `sed` or adding to end of sources.list via `cat`

There are multiple questions here that helps with that.

Of course you can also edit manually via a text editor like `nano`.

`nano` has search and replace functions as well.

Comment: +1 for `sed`, and then use something like capistrano to run it on all your servers.

Answer (score 1):

Just edit the `/etc/apt/sources.list` using your favorite text editor for e.g.

```
sudo emacs /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Since you have other repos listed already in the file the syntax is fairly clear. You will obviously need to know the address of the repo you are adding.